# Calculate coordinates for octagon

Tags: geometry

How to get 8 coordinates for octagon?
I have the following data regarding octagon -

1. length of the octagon side.
2. starting point.

Now I need to know how to get the 8 coordinates of the octagon.

Comment: Do you know how to draw other shapes, like a square? Do you have code for that? Or is it just about the calculation?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You need to provide some code showing your effort to solve this, and of course tagging your question accodingly to reflect which language you're using. I also have the feeling this question is more about mathematics/geometry than programming as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately an octagon is a relatively easy shape, because the lines are octogonal or diagonally at 45 degrees. So you don't need more complex calculations. For a triangle with a right angle and two sides of the same length Y, the hypotenuse of that triangle has a a length Y * sqrt(2).

That hypothenuse is your side X, so Y = X / sqrt(2).

Picture saying more than 1000 words:
[image]

So you can calculate Y for your desired length X, and from there it's just additions and subtractions to get all the coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a *regular* octagon *centered at the origin*, the starting point is at

```
(x, y) = (r cos(t), r sin(t))
```

where `t` is the starting angle and `r` the radius of the circumscribed circle. 
You find them by conversion to polar coordinates,

```
r = √x²+y², tan(t) = y/x
```

but this is unnecessary.

The other vertices are at

```
(x, y) = (r cos(t + k π/4), r sin(t + k π/4))
```

You can simplify the formula by the angle addition formula. For instance, for the second vertex

```
(r (cos(t) - sin(t))/√2, r (sin(t) + cos(t))/√2) = ((x - y)/√2, (x + y)/√2)
```

and for the third

```
(r (-sin(t)), r cos(t)) = (-y, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you came here just looking for the points, like me, here they are.

These are (x, y) coordinates for an octagon like a stop sign (equal sides and flat on the top). Note that the `0.414` values are actually `sqrt(2) - 1`. These coordinates make an octagon with sides of length `2 * (sqrt(2) - 1)`. For an octagon with sides of length `S`, multiply each value by `S/(2 * (sqrt(2) - 1))`.

```
( 0.414, 1.000)
( 1.000, 0.414)
( 1.000, -0.414)
( 0.414, -1.000)
(-0.414, -1.000)
(-1.000, -0.414)
(-1.000, 0.414)
(-0.414, 1.000)
```